# Python Tkinter combobox dropdown appear topleft screen corner

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I face a strange issue with the Tkinter combobox. I run this simple GUI with a combobox. A month ago, on my windows 10 the tkinter combobox start to appear at topleft corner instead of below the arrow.

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
window = Tk()
window.title("ComboBox list down test")
window.geometry('350x200')
combo = Combobox(window)
combo['values']= (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, "Text")
combo.current(1) #set the selected item
combo.grid(column=0, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

I run python 3.7.7 (I try newer version and it is not fixing the issue)

Here is a preview of what i mean:
[drop list on the topleft corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVZrR.png)

When using another windows 10 with the same python 3.7.7 the combobox is ok:
[Combobox normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oLqJ.png)

This behavior start appening on my gui out of nowhere. It start doing this a month ago.
Is there propertie on the combobox to make it display correctly.

Is someone facing the same issue?

Comment: Am i the only one facing this issue.... I got the same problem in TCL TK and the only way to fix it was to change the tclsh.exe shell to tclsh85.exe but both of the exe file come from the same installation of active tcl 8.5. Now it is with python Tkinter. Anyone have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using the wrong library. You should import `tkinter` instead of `tkinter.ttk`.
I changed your script and it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

use this code

change from **combo = Combobox(window)** to **combo = ttk.Combobox(window)**

```
from tkinter import ttk

combo = ttk.Combobox(window)
```

Comment: Could you clarify what difference it would make? Judging from tkinter's source code, the `tkinter.ttk` module [would export the same `Combobox` class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ea46c7bc503d1103d60c0ec7023bb52c5defa11d/Lib/tkinter/ttk.py#L19) for the original code posted by @Flabada.